# Delphi json array without bracket

Tags: arrays, json, delphi

```json
{
      "code": 0,
      "data": {
        "KAVAUSDT": {
          "name": "KAVAUSDT",
          "min_amount": "0.5",
          "maker_fee_rate": "0.003",
          "taker_fee_rate": "0.003",
          "pricing_name": "USDT",
          "pricing_decimal": 4,
          "trading_name": "KAVA",
          "trading_decimal": 8
        },
        "CFXUSDT": {
          "name": "CFXUSDT",
          "min_amount": "5",
          "maker_fee_rate": "0.003",
          "taker_fee_rate": "0.003",
          "pricing_name": "USDT",
          "pricing_decimal": 6,
          "trading_name": "CFX",
          "trading_decimal": 8
        },
        ... continue 
      }
    }
```

If there were `[` and `]` symbols, I could solve it quickly with `TJsonArray`:

```pascal
...

JsonArray := JsonValue.GetValue<TJSONArray>('data');

for ArrayElement in JsonArray do
begin
  tempName           := ArrayElement.GetValue<String>('name');
  tempPricingName    := ArrayElement.GetValue<String>('pricing_name');   
  ...
end;
```

There are no `[`and `]` symbols in this Json type.

Without the `[` and `]` symbols, I cannot access the data, as it is using a `for` loop.

Is there a simple solution?

Comment: That's not an array, it's an object

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is no array in the JSON document you have shown. `"KAVAUSDT"`, `"CFXUSDT"`, etc are not array elements, they are simply named object fields of the `"data"` object. If you need to loop through the child fields of the `"data"` object, you can use `TJSONObject` (not `TJSONArray`!) for that, eg:

```pascal
...

JsonObj := JsonValue.GetValue<TJSONObject>('data');

for Field in JsonObj do
begin
  FieldObj           := Field.JsonValue as TJSONObject;
  tempName           := FieldObj.GetValue<String>('name');
  tempPricingName    := FieldObj.GetValue<String>('pricing_name');   
  ...
end;
```

Comment: {
      "code": 0,
      "data": {
        "PGN": {
          "available": "17106.09093508",
          "frozen": "0"
        },
        "USDT": {
          "available": "164.43456092",
          "frozen": "0"
        } ,
        ... ,
        ... ,
        ... ,
        ... 
      },
      "message": "Succeeded"
    }

How Can i read Header key like "PGN" , "USDT" , "???"  ....

Comment: @AbdullahYılmaz the exact same way I showed in my answer. `Field.JsonString` is the name (`PGN`, `USDT`, etc) and `Field.JsonValue` is the `TJSONObject` where `available`, `frozen`, etc can be accessed from.